# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_row()

Tags: php

soy nuevo en está comunidad y también en esto de la programación en general.
Verán, este es mi error cuando completo el formulario de logueo:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\AcademySoftware\Controlador\Autenticador.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\AcademySoftware\Controlador\Autenticador.php on line 21

Es algo extraño... Llevo horas intentando solucionar esto

````
session_start();
$Servidor = "localhost";
$Usuario = "root";
$DataBase = "AcademySoftware";
$Password = "";

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$Conexion = mysqli_connect($Servidor, $Usuario, $Password, $DataBase) or die($msj);
if (!$Conexion) {
    die("No se puede entrar a la base de datos. Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$iniciador = $_POST['Validacion'];
if (isset($iniciador)) {
    $Id_Usuario = $_POST['Id_Usuario'];
    $Contraseña_Usuario = $_POST['Contraseña_Usuario'];

    $sql="SELECT Id_Usuario, Contraseña_Usuario, concat(Nombres_Usuario,' ',Apellidos_Usuario), Id.Tipo_Usuario from usuario where Id_Usuario='$Id_Usuario' and Contraseña_Usuario = '$Contraseña_Usuario'";
    $res = $Conexion->query($sql);
    $fila=$res->fetch_row();                                                      //Línea 21

    if ($fila[1] == $Id_Usuario && $fila[10] == $Contraseña_Usuario) {

        $_SESSION['Id.Tipo_Usuario'] = $fila[3];
        $_SESSION['Nombres_Usuario'] = $fila[4];

        $mjs = "Bienvenido " . $_SESSION['Nombres_Usuario'] . "";

        switch ($_SESSION['Id.Tipo_Usuario']) {
            case '0':
                header('location:../Vista/App/Roles/Estudiante/index.php');
                break;
            case '1':
                header('location:../Vista/App/Roles/Acudiente/index.php');
                break;
            case '2':
                header('location:../Vista/App/Roles/Profesor/index.php');
                break;
            case '3':
                header('location:../Vista/App/Roles/Coordinador/index.php');
                break;
            case '4':
                header('location:../Vista/App/Roles/Rector/index.php');
                break;
            case '5':
                header('location:../Vista/App/Roles/Administrador/index.php');
                break;
            default:
                header('location:../Vista/App/Roles/Estudiante/index.php');
                break;
        }
    } else {
        $msj = "Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrectos";
        header('location:../Vista/index.php?mensaje=$msj');
    }
}```

Sí puedes ser claros, ayudaría demasiado, ¡gracias!
````

Comment: Ese error suele ocurrir cuando la consulta falla, debido a problemas de sintaxis u otros. Esto podría ser problemático: `Id.Tipo_Usuario` porque ahí `Id` sería una tabla que no existe en la instrucción SQL. De todos modos, tu código necesita una profunda revisión. Recomendaría que uses consultas preparadas para evitar *inyección SQL*, que evites el uso de `ñ` u otros caracteres especiales y acentos, que controles la codificación y captures los errores.

Comment: Hola. Sí existe dicha tabla y mire bien ese problema, gracias por tu revisión :)

Comment: No existe en la instrucción, a eso me refiero, por tanto, la instrucción SQL: `SELECT Id_Usuario, Contraseña_Usuario, concat(Nombres_Usuario,' ',Apellidos_Usuario), Id.Tipo_Usuario from usuario where Id_Usuario='$Id_Usuario' and Contraseña_Usuario = '$Contraseña_Usuario'` sería errónea porque intentas usar una tabla que no has incluido en la misma.

Comment: Entiendo, el error como tal está en la tabla de usuarios dentro mi base de datos. Creo encontrar una forma de poder solucionarlo, ¡gracias por la revisión!